# Turbomachines numerical please help

Tags: fluid-mechanics, turbomachinery

A twin jet Pelton wheel has a mean runner diameter of 1.68
m & runs at 500rpm, each jet is of dia. 152 mm. The net
head is 510 m. Bucket turns the jet through 1650 & relative
velocity is reduced by 12% when it flows over the bucket.
Windage & mechanical losses are 3% of the water power
supplied. Nozzle co-efficient = 0.98. Find:

i)
Water power supplied.
ii)
Brake power.
iii)
Force of each jet on bucket.
iv)
Overall efficiency.

Comment: Bucket turns the jet through 165 degrees

Comment: Hint: P = Qgh where q is flow rate, g is gravity and h is head.

Comment: @Pranith edit the post ... do not write a comment that makes a correction ... also, please add a clear, answerable question to your post